# Derive an atlas of Monge patches for a surface in 3D

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, parametric

> **Question:** If I have an atlas of non-monge charts for a surface, how I can I derive an atlas of monge charts?

In differential geometry, a 'Monge patch' is a chart of the form $f(u,v) = (u, v, h(u,v))$. [2]

In simple terms, it's a parametric equation for a 3D surface patch described by only a height function.

This section from *Solid Shape* (Koenderink, MIT Press 1990 - p. 233) describes Monge patch representation of surfaces and motivates my interest in learning how to derive them.

> The Monge patch representation lends itself particularly well for
>   visualizations and for quick and dirty "back of the envelope"
>   calculations. You should thoroughly familiarize yourself with it. In a
>   local frame you can always use the Monge patch representation for a
>   small neighborhood. **Very often you can cover whole surfaces with just
>   a few Monge patches.**

An 'atlas' is a set of charts that cover a surface (a differentiable manifold) so what the author is saying is you can often produce an atlas for a surface where every chart is in Monge form.

Typically in the literature on differential geometry, charts for surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are not given in Monge form.

---

As a specific clarifying example here is a typical non-monge chart on a torus. [3]

\begin{align}
x &= c + a*\cos(v)*\cos(u)\\
y &= c + a*\cos(v)*\sin(u)\\
z &= c + a*\sin(v)
\end{align}

$$f(u,v) = (x,y,z)$$

How can I produce an atlas of Monge charts for the torus? That is, a list of parametric equations for surface patches that cover every part of a torus and are all in Monge form.

Specifically, I'd like to understand the process of working the problem in general for simple surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, not just the list of equations for the torus.

---

Here is a visualization of one Monge chart for a torus and its domain. The parametric question for a surface patch like this is what I'm interested in. [4]

[image]
[2] http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MongePatch.html

[3] http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html

[4] http://faculty.cooper.edu/smyth/DifferentialGeometry/ch4/torusMonge.htm

Comment: To get Monge patches you need a cartesian equation for the surface, since you need to be able to write it locally as a graph over the $xy$-, $yz$-, or $xz$-plane. So use your parametric equations to deduce the cartesian equation of the torus.

Comment: 'use your parametric equations to deduce the cartesian equation of the torus' is essentially what I'm asking how to do. Do you have any guidance there?

"cartesian equation" is a useful hint thank you!

Comment: You can use obvious trig identities to lead yourself to it. But remember that a surface of revolution has symmetry about (in your case) the $z$-axis, and this means that it's obtained by rotating a curve in the $yz$-plane ($g(y,z)=0$, say) about the $z$-axis. So you get $f(x,y,z)=0$ where $f(x,y,z)=g(?,z)$?

Comment: By the way, I think people are getting over-zealous with closing questions here. I voted to re-open. I didn't give a complete answer because you will learn more for thinking it through for yourself, but I realize that annoys some of the folks on MSE.

Answer (score 1):

Your torus is a function $f : (u,v) \rightarrow (x,y,z)$.

If you choose a xy-point $(a,b)$, you can make monge patch using the following: $(a,b,h(a,b))$.

To connect $f$ with the monge patch, you'll do: $(x=a, y=b, z=h(a,b))$.

To calculate $(u,v)$ out of chosen $(a,b)$, you can do inverse image of $f$:
  $$ f^{-1}((x=a,y=b,z=h(a,b))) : (x,y,z) \rightarrow (u,v)$$
  $$ f^{-1}[B] = \{ x \in X | f(x) \in B \} $$

To calculate this inverse image, we need a function $g : (x,y,z) \rightarrow 2$, which can be given by:
$$ g(x,y,z) = ((x=a) \And (y=b)) $$

Once we have $g$ function, we can compose it with $f$ to get:
  $$ (g \circ f)(u,v) = g(f(u,v)) : (u,v) \rightarrow 2$$. The result we want comes from the equation:
 $$ (g \circ f)(u,v) = {true} $$. This allows us to calculate
$(u,v)$.

Now that we have $(u,v)$, we can use $f$ to obtain $(x,y,z)$.
Then from that, we get $z=h(a,b)$ as required.

excersize to the reader: try the pattern with the actual torus formulas.